# How to pass regular expression pattern as a variable to grep?

Tags: regex, shell

For example, I have a regex to match `xx-xx-xxx`: `[a-z0-9]{2}-[a-z0-9]{2}-[a-z0-9]{3}`, I want to store it to a variable so I can keep referring to it in my program. Here is what I tried:

```
pattern="[a-z0-9]{2}-[a-z0-9]{2}-[a-z0-9]"
grep -i "here:$pattern" file.log # assuming that my log file has "hi:xx-xx-xxx" pattern strings.
```

No results are returned but if I execute:

```
grep -i "here:[a-z0-9]{2}-[a-z0-9]{2}-[a-z0-9]" file.log
```

It works. What did I do wrong?

Comment: use `set -x` to see the interpolation of variable values as your cmd is being executed. Compare what you see there to your hard-coded version and then escape chars as need to get the same results. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I see the variables as my program executes. Maybe i should open a new thread... But it still seems very relevant here: the grep took a single quote as a result even though I used double quotes everywhere.. any suggestion to fix that?

Comment: I should have mentioned that. The single quote view is the shells way of showing "This is as far as I can rationalize what I have converted" . A single quoted string will also show up as single-quoted. And (I think) the shell will even single-quote strings where no quotes (of any type) where used, just to make clear "what it is processing" . Just edit your Q with the `set -x` view and add your comments about what still is not working. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to escape the curly brackets like so `\{2\}` or use the extended regexp mode of grep via the `-E` flag.
Thus it'll be either

```
pattern='[a-z0-9]{2}-[a-z0-9]{2}-[a-z0-9]{3}'
echo "hi:aa-00-xxx" | grep -iE "hi:$pattern"
```

or

```
pattern='[a-z0-9]\{2\}-[a-z0-9]\{2\}-[a-z0-9]\{3\}'
echo "hi:aa-00-xxx" | grep -i "hi:$pattern"
```

Comment: I used egrep instead of grep -E for the first case, but still same results. Any idea? I try to avoid escaping my {} because that will make it hard to read.

Comment: egrep for the first case worked fine for me as well. Testing it on RHEL 6.7 btw. I'd suggest you use single quotes for the ```pattern``` var. Also, what exact pattern are you using - with or without the trailing ```{3}``` ?

Comment: Does the "variable substitution" fail only when used in your program, or also from the command line? Could you post a complete transscript from the commandline, which shows the error, including doing an `echo` on the variable containing the pattern?